# getting Missing opening '(' after keyword error in ffmpeg loop command

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

How can I run this command that runs in Linux in Windows 10 powershell for ffmpeg?

```
for file in D:\input\*.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -map 0:s:1 -c:v copy -c:a flac -c:s copy D:\output; done
```

I tried

```
for file in D:\input\*.mkv; do ./ffmpeg -i "$file" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -map 0:s:1 -c:v copy -c:a flac -c:s copy D:\output; done
```

But I get this error:

```
At line:1 char:4
+ for file in D:\input\*.mkv; do ./ffmpeg -i "$fil ...
+    ~
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
At line:1 char:52
+ for file in D:\input\*.mkv; do ./ffmpeg -i "$fil ...
+                                                    ~
Missing statement body in do loop.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword
```

So how can I change this command to run properly in Windows 10 powershell?

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, PowerShell does not recognize `bash`'s `for` loop syntax.

In PowerShell, you'd do something like this instead:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\input -Filter *.mkv |ForEach-Object {
  ./ffmpeg -i $_.FullName -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:s:0 -map 0:s:1 -c:v copy -c:a flac -c:s copy D:\output
}
```

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen where do you define $_.FullName

Comment: @vivofen578 I don't need to! :) `ForEach-Object` automatically assigns the current item in the loop to `$_` - since `Get-ChildItem` returns [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) objects, `$_.FullName` will resolve to the full path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

use rather 'Developer Command Prompt for vs 2022' than powershell(in windows Terminal).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).